# In Android , How to manage Layouts if i have to submit more than 50 input fields ?

Tags: android

In Android , How to manage Layouts if i have to submit more than 50 input fields ? like five Steps, and every step having 10 input element.

What should be used to manage lengthy input data ?

Comment: A `ScrollView` container?

Comment: perhaps you can make it one activity per step

Comment: u can use a `ScrollView` but Please keep in mind if any layout **has more than 80 views, that is bad for performance**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use **`android:weightSum`** attribute in parent layout file & **`android:layout_weight`** in each child view
- Use Vertical ScrollView & Set **`android:fillViewport="true"`**
- Use 5 **`Fragments`** & each must contain 10 Input Fields.Use 2 Buttons (As Fwd & Bwd) for Navigation.
- Make some validation as all fields are mandatory.